# undefined on getting specific value from State array - React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I'm reading data from firestore and stores it in state array of objects.

when i

`console.log(this.state.array)`

it returns the whole array with all the data of the objects, but when i

`console.log(this.state.array.name)`

or

`console.log(this.state.array[0])`

> it returns undefined

.

I have tried to get the data with

**forEach**

loop but it seems to be not working as well.

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { tips: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        firebase.firestore().collection('pendingtips').get()
            .then(doc => { 
                doc.forEach(tip => { 
                    this.setState([...tips], tip.data()); 
                    console.log(this.state.tips);
                }); 
            })
            .catch(() => Alert.alert('error'));
    }

    renderTips() {
        console.log(this.state.tips); //returns the whole array as expected
        console.log(this.state.tips[0].name); //returns undefined
        return this.state.tips.map(tip => <PendingTip key={tip.tip} name={tip.name} tip={tip.tip} />); //return null because tip is undefined
    } 
   render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
                <ScrollView style={styles.tipsContainerStyle}>
                    {this.renderTips()}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

the array structure is:

```
"tips": [
    { name: "X", tip: "Y" },
    { name: "Z", tip: "T" }
]
```

so I expect this.state.tips[0].name will be "X" instead of undefined.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share print screen of this array in beakpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found out that the problem was that JavaScript saves arrays as objects.
for example this array:

```
[ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ]
```

is equal to:

```
{
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
  length: 3
}
```

"You get undefined when you try to access the array value at index 0, but it’s not that the value undefined is stored at index 0, it’s that the default behavior in JavaScript is to return undefined if you try to access the value of an object for a key that does not exist."
[as written in this article](https://itnext.io/heres-why-mapping-a-constructed-array-doesn-t-work-in-javascript-f1195138615a)

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you should fetch data in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call

2. Secondly, you should use `this.setState` to update your state, instead of mutating it directly.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("pendingtips")
      .get()
      .then(docs => {
        const tips = docs.map(doc => doc.data());

        this.setState({ tips });
      })
      .catch(() => Alert.alert("error"));
  }
```

Comment: can you show us your render method? not `renderTips`

Comment: Changed it to ComponentDidMount but the main problem is with the state array, the this.state.array.push(object) actually worked for me. the problem was that I couldn't fetch the data from the state array properly

Answer (score 0):

`firesore` requests are `async`, so by time your request gets execute your component is getting mounted and in a result you are getting undefined for your state in console.

You must do API call in `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.

Mutating/changing state like this, will not trigger re-render of component and your component will not get latest data,

```
doc.forEach(tip => { 
      this.state.tips.push(tip.data()); 
      console.log(this.state.tips);
});
```

You must use `setState` to change your state, doing this your component will get re-render and you have latest data all the time.

```
componentDidMount(){
  firebase.firestore().collection('pendingtips').get()
     .then(doc => { 
         const tipsData = doc.map(tip => tip.data());
         this.setState({tips:tipsData},() => console.log(this.state.tips));
     })
     .catch(() => Alert.alert('error'));
}
```

While calling `renderTips` function make sure your state array has data,

```
{this.state.tips.length > 0 && this.renderTips()}
```

Comment: doesn't work as well... passing me straight to .catch

Comment: Changed it to ComponentDidMount but the main problem is with the state array, the this.state.array.push(object) actually worked for me. the problem was that I couldn't fetch the data from the state array proparly

Comment: You can do this, `{this.state.tips.length > 0 && this.renderTips()}`

Comment: What  console.log(this.state.tips) print's?

Comment: Also try to print `doc` in your API response.

Comment: it prints an empty array, it goes straight to catch

Comment: Have you replaced your code with my code, and if it still goes to .catch then your API is not responding.

Comment: Can you write your updated code here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react